# androidx package not imported. (in grey color. like unused imports)

Tags: android, android-studio

i have cloned a gitlab repository to a laptop. the import statements are gray in color(like unused imports). so the classes are full of errors. initially i was using this same project in another laptop. there everything was fine. should i download something or should i change some settings. the previous laptop had android studio version 3.4. this laptop is having studio version 3.3.1. does this version make any difference. 
also in settings page, project-level settings is collapsed. it is not expanded. i dont know if there is any path set or default gradle wrapper is used. is this the reason for the problem?

Comment: click the button to sync with gradle

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i invalidated cache and restarted. the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your project with androidX by following below procedure

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

To migrate an existing project that does not use any third-party libraries with dependencies that need converting, you can set the android.useAndroidX flag to true and the `android.enableJetifier` flag to false.

also add missing dependency in your `build.gradle` file

check list of dependencies over [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: thanks for you time and effort. i invalidated the cache and restarted. the problem is solved

Comment: @VijaiGunasekar okay